# MsgPack Serialization in .Net 2.0

Tags: c#, android, performance, serialization, messagepack

I want to use a fast Serialization for exchange byte data from .NET 2.0 application, .NET 4.0 application and Android application.
[Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRrXo.png)

The problem is that the NuGet MessagePack packet is only for .NET 4.0 and I can't serialize data whit the .NET 2.0 application.
I haven't problem whit Android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to compile the MessagePack package for .Net 2.0 from https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli.  You may need to do some work to get it compiled for .Net 2.0.